# What's the closest equivalent to Python's any/all functions in Swift?

Tags: swift

In Python, the built-in "any" and "all" functions return true iff any of the elements in an iterable are true or iff all of the elements in an iterable are true, respectively. For example:

```
any([False, False, False]) # evaluates to False
any([False, False, True]) # evaluates to True
all([True, True, False]) # evaluates to False
all([True, True, True]) # evaluates to True
```

Is there anything like this in Swift? If not, what's the most concise way to achieve the same result? The best I have come up with is:

```
elements.reduce(true, {x, y in x && y}) // for "all"
elements.reduce(false, {x, y in x || y}) // for "any"
```

Comment: Compare [Does Swift have short-circuiting higher-order functions like Any or All?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44337137/does-swift-have-short-circuiting-higher-order-functions-like-any-or-all)

Comment: Btw you can write your closures in short form, i.e.
`elements.reduce(true, &&)` and `elements.reduce(false, ||)`

Answer (score 4):

```
let any = elements.contains(true)
let all = !elements.contains(false)
```

Swift extends this with `contains(where:)` which you can use to evaluate any predicate.

Comment: You can use `contains(where:)` to apply any rule you like. There is no such thing as "truthy" in Swift. Booleans are true. 1 is not "true". (Truthiness is quite subtle at times. Should the string "0" be true or false? How about the strings "0x00" or "false" or "not"? Swift avoids all this.)